# Querying by post category slug with core/query block markup

Tags: theme-development, query, tax-query

I know how to query all posts in a certain category by slug with `WP_Query`. What I would like to do is the same with the `core/query` block markup. I am able to get it working with the category ID, but I'd like to do it by slug as the target category has a different ID in development and production installations. I know I could check the domain, but I'd rather save a check if possible.

'news' is the target category slug. I've tried the following:

```
<!-- wp:query {"query":{"postType":"post","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"taxQuery":{"taxonomy":"category","field":"slug","terms":["news"]}}} -->


<!-- wp:query {"query":{"postType":"post","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"categoryName":"news"}} -->
```

but both show all the posts. As far as I understand it, the markup passes the query arguments unmodified into the underlying `WP_Query` function, but maybe this is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the `taxQuery` value, or that it should always be in the form of `{"<taxonomy>":[<term IDs>],"<taxonomy>":[<term IDs>],"<taxonomy>":[<term IDs>],...}`.

But you can add custom arguments, so `"categoryName":"news"` is good.

And then you can use the [`query_loop_block_query_vars` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_loop_block_query_vars/) to add the category slug to the `WP_Query` arguments coming from the Query Loop block.

Here's an example where I used `tax_query` ( and not `category_name` ):

```php
// `categoryName` is not part of `$query` (because `categoryName` is a custom
// argument), but it is stored in the `$block->context['query']` array, which
// explains why we need the second parameter, i.e. `$block`.
function my_filter_query_loop_block_query_vars( $query, $block ) {
    if ( ! empty( $block->context['query']['categoryName'] ) ) {
        $tax_query = isset( $query['tax_query'] ) ? (array) $query['tax_query'] : array();

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms'    => $block->context['query']['categoryName'],
            'field'    => 'slug',
        );

        $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR';

        $query['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'query_loop_block_query_vars', 'my_filter_query_loop_block_query_vars', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but the question is specifically about using the Gutenberg block markup. Are you saying this filter will allow me to use the `categoryName` query parameter in the block markup?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The markup alone will not work because `categoryName` is not a standard query [argument](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/v16.7.0/packages/block-library/src/query/block.json#L16-L28) supported by the Query Loop block. That's what my answer was trying to show to you.